# Java is not installed unix issue

Tags: java, datastax, java-home, opscenter

I am on Linux Centos 6.

I've installed Java JRE and JDK on my machine.

```
[root@mhsapp002 conf]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)


[root@mhsapp002 conf]# javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55
```

Also, I've manually set JAVA_HOME in `.bash_profile` file.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jre1.7.0_60
export PATH=/opt/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin:$PATH


[root@mhsapp002 conf]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/jre1.7.0_60
```

Also, I've tried set both options in using `alternatives`.

```
[root@mhsapp002 conf]# alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /opt/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java
*+ 2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java



[root@mhsapp002 conf]# readlink -f $(which java)
/opt/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java
```

Now I am trying to install datastax opscenter-agent which requires java on the machine. But it fails with following error:

Some agent installations failed:

```
- 127.0.0.1: Failure installing agent on 127.0.0.1.
Standard output:
Unable to find a java executable!
Please install java or set JAVA_HOME.

Exit code: 4
```

Do you have any ideas or suggestions for what reason it is fails? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does datastax require full JDK or just a JRE?

Comment: @NickJ, I've installed JDK by running following command: `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel` Is it safe to assume that I've installed full JDK? `java` and `javac` cmds works fine.

Comment: what's the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Yes it looks like you do have JDK. Just a thought.

Comment: `alternatives --config java` may help you...

Comment: @طاهر, I've tried both selections using alternatives. No luck!

Comment: i think it is a Centos bug see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77290/alternatives-not-working-well-for-java-installation-on-centos-6-4

Comment: Just a wild guess but try with Oracle JDK instead of openjdk.

Comment: Post the output of `readlink -f $(which java)` . This the java CentOS is using.

Comment: Did you do `source ~/.bashrc` after setting `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: @bsd, I did it, same effect. :/

Answer (score 6):

There is a problem with provisioning OpsCenter Agents on Centos 6.5. It should be fixed in upcoming patch releases of Datastax OpsCenter.

If you’re installing agents on the existing Cassandra cluster, there’s a workaround: try installing and starting agents manually (via `yum` and `service`, accordingly).